# How do I export a variable from a p5.js file and then import it into THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, p5.js

I have a p5.js script that draws a perlin noise Canva that I later turn into a variable. Then I need that variable to be imported into a THREE.js file to be used as texture. It returns me an error saying that the variable that I export is not defined.

I used "export { variable };" in the p5.js script and it return an error saying that export is not defined. In the second file I use "import { variable } from './filename.js' }; and it returns an error saying that the variable in the other file is not defined.

First file (uses p5.js):

```
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(800, 400);
    noStroke();

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x+=1) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y+=1) {
            var c = 255 * noise(0.01 * x, 0.01 * y);
            fill(c);
            rect(x, y, 10, 10);
        }   
    }
    //return image from canvas
    //(gets the entire image when it is not specified any parameter)
}

var map = get();

if (map==null) {
    console.log("no export");
}

// noprotect
//export { map };
```

Second file (uses THREE.js):

```
import { map } from 'http://[...].org/js/perlin.js';
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are few obvious problems:

1. p5.js in global mode is fundamentally incompatible with ES modules
2. They way your code is structured the call to the p5.js get() function would happen before setup() actually got called in any case.
3. It's not clear why the export statement is commented out

### ES Modules & p5.js

When you create an ES module, none of the top level declarations in your module are available globally (which in the context of a web browser means as properties of the `window` object). The way p5.js works is it looks for a global `setup` function and if one is declared it invokes it followed by other global functions it supports such as `draw`. So if you put your `setup` function in a module it will not be called by p5.js unless you explicitly assign it to `window.setup`. To perform some p5.js drawing commands when your module is loaded you should be able to use [Instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).

### How to make an ES Module that exports p5.Graphics

You p5.Graphics creating module should look something like this:

```
// we need a p5 instance in order to use createGraphics, but we don't need
// any default display canvas
let p5Inst = new p5(p => {
  p.setup = () => { p.noCanvas(); };
});

export const example = p5Inst.createGraphics(200, 200);

example.fill('blue');
example.circle(100, 100, 100);
```

This would allow you to write another module that imports `example` and uses it however you like.

### Using a `p5.Graphics` object in a THREE.js App

Once you have successfully exported your `p5.Graphics` object from your module, the next step is to actually apply that correctly in your THREE.js app. The main thing to remember here is that `p5.Graphics` is a p5.js specific wrapper for the native `Canvas` element. THREE.js has good support for using a canvas as a texture, so all you need to do is access the `elt` property of the `p5.Graphics` instance. Here's the full code of a working THREE.js scene, which is mostly boilerplate code:

```
import * as THREE from '/lib/three.module.js';
import { example } from '/graphics.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

// We have to get the Canvas element from the p5.Graphics wrapper to use this
// as a texture in THREE.js
const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(example.elt);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
```

Here's a full working example hosted on Replit: https://replit.com/@KumuPaul/three-js-p5js-integration#sketch.js

Comment: I changed the file in the way u said:
    export const noise = p5Inst.createGraphics(800, 400);

    [...]
    for (var x = 0; x < 800; x+=0.5) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 400; y+=0.5) {
   var c = 255 * noise(0.01 * x, 0.01 * y);
   noise.fill(c);
   rect(x, y, 10, 10);
   } 
    }

But I get this error on the THREE.js page: "caught TypeError: noise is not a function".

Comment: In order to provide any more assistance you will need to provide a minimal reproducible example in your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Go to http://fagnanialessiohtml.altervista.org/pages/tries/sphere.html

Comment: try `p5Inst.noise` instead of just the global `noise`. Nothing from p5.js will available globally in this context. It will either by on the `p5` import (in the case of things like `p5.Vector` and `p5.Graphics`, on the p5 instance `p5inst` in the case of constants like `PI` or `RADIANS`, or on the `pg.Graphics` instance in the case of drawing functions like `line` or `beginShape`.

Comment: After switching it to p5Inst.noise it returns a dark texture with just a lighter circular spot instead of the perlin noise. For a working example go to the same link as above and refresh cache.